# What are QueryRecyclerProvider in an Apollo context?

Tags: reactjs, debugging, apollo

I just realized that my app was wrapped with QueryRecyclerProvider after I've switched my backend technology (from an express (nodejs) apollo server to a Python Graphene, so what's this Component role?

[image]

Will it impact the normal behavior of my app?

I notice that when I was clicking on store tab into Chrome Apollo Extension Add-in, it makes extension crash.